# Sobrecarga de Funciones en Python con parámetro *args

Tags: python, python-3.x, parametros

Estoy haciendo el siguiente ejercicio

Enunciado:
Definir una función max(), que te devuelva el número más alto de lo introducido por parámetros:

a) De x número de parámetros

b) De una lista

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
# apartado a)
def max_a(*args):
  dev = args[0]
  for x in args:
    if x > dev:
      dev = x

  return dev

# apartado b)
def max_b(lst):
  dev = lst[0]
  for x in lst:
    if x > dev:
      dev = x

  return dev


print(max_a(1,20,3,4,5))    # Función con *args de param
print(max_b([1,20,3,4,5]))  # Función con una lista de param
```

El output de las dos funciones me da 20, funcionan bien.

Me gustaría hacer una sobrecarga para llamar a las dos funciones con el mismo nombre (max).

Yo suelo utilizar el decorador @dispatch() de la librería multipledispatch para estas cosas, pero no encuentro la forma de hacerlo con el tipo de parámetro *args

Gracias por leer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una solución general es crear un función que reciba el/los parámetros y decida a cual versión llamar:

```
def mi_max(*objeto):
    if isinstance(objeto[0], list):
        return max_b(*objeto)
    else:
        return max_a(*objeto)
```

El "*" delante del parámetro hace que los argumentos recibidos se pongan en una **tupla**. Lo que tenemos que hacer es examinar el primer elemento de esa tupla:

- Si es una lista, llamar a `max_b`.
- Si no, llamar a `max_a`.

Fijate que en la llamada a `max_a/max_b` vuelvo a colocar un "*" delante del argumento. Si no pongo el "*", estaria pasando la tupla. Si recibo una lista, no quiero pasarla encapsulada en una tupla; quiero pasar el contenido de ella (elemento cero).

#### Segunda versión

Sin embargo, en este ejemplo podemos resumir más la situación: no necesitamos dos funciones distintas según el tipo de argumento; lo podemos hacer con una sola función, pues siempre recibo una lista o tupla sobre la cual puedo iterar.

```
def max_a(*objeto):
    if isinstance(objeto[0], list):
        args = objeto[0]
    else:
        args = objeto

    dev = None
    for x in args:
        if dev is None or x > dev:
          dev = x

    return dev
```

#### Demo

```
def max_a(*objeto):
    if isinstance(objeto[0], list):
        args = objeto[0]
    else:
        args = objeto

    dev = None
    for x in args:
        if dev is None or x > dev:
          dev = x

    return dev

print(max_a(1,20,3,4,5))    # Función con *args de param
print(max_a([1,20,3,4,5]))  # Función con una lista de param
```

produce:

```
20
20

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta